# rails 4 - cannot capitalize a localized utf-8 string correctly when first character is accentuated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n, capitalization

I have a localized string :

```
en:
  doorkeeper:
      device: device
fr:
  doorkeeper:
      device: équipement
```

capitalizing the string using I18n.locale = :fr is incorrect ( in french an initial capitalized letter is never accentuated)

```
I18n.t(:device, scope: :doorkeeper)    => "équipement"
 I18n.t(:device, scope: :doorkeeper).capitalize  => "équipement"
```

I can bypass it w parameterize before capitalize

```
I18n.t(:device, scope: :doorkeeper).parameterize.capitalize => "Equipement"
```

but parameterize removes all accentuated characters... which is not a generic solution ..

I can  use .mb_char, but still the first character is capitalized and accentuated :

```
'équipement'.mb_chars.capitalize.to_s => "Équipement
```

I tried to use the [unicode-utils gem](https://github.com/lang/unicode_utils) , but it generates also a capitalized accentuated string ...   any sother olutions adding inflectors ?